# innertext does not run in certain url

Tags: javascript

I need to read the "uploaded-date" from this url:

https://www.youtube.com/tv?vq=high#/watch/video/control?v=hqwU7nv3hTM&resume

Using this code:

```
window.alert(document.getElementsByClassName("uploaded-date")[0].innerText);
```

I got the error "Cannot read property 'innerText' of undefined".

If i use the same method in this url:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hqwU7nv3hTM

with the code:

```
window.alert(document.getElementsByClassName("ytp-time-duration")[0].innerText);
```

where i only change the class name all runs well.

i don't understand where is my problem.

Any idea?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You want it to return when it was published? this does that 'window.alert(document.getElementsByClassName("watch-time-text")[0].innerText);'

Comment: I got the error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerText' of undefined

Comment: Sorry. This works on the second url. But i need to get from the first url: https://www.youtube.com/tv?vq=high#/watch/video/control?v=hqwU7nv3hTM&resume

Comment: try this: window.alert(document.getElementsByClassName("uploaded-date")[0].innerText);

Comment: Nevermind, just realised that's the same as yours! Still works for me though on FF. There seems to be an issue with pasting it from here, try typing it manually.

Comment: i got the error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerText' of undefined REMEMBER, the url for test is: https://www.youtube.com/tv?vq=high#/watch/video/idle?v=hqwU7nv3hTM&resume

Comment: Can you provide the code where you are trying to read that property? As was alrady said, the code works fine when executed in console but it won't work if you are embeding it on your website so providing more code is essential for finidng a solution.

Comment: the problem is the page is not loaded when i execute the code. I need then to wait to the page is completly loaded. I will look for how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is about the load content.
When the script start, the page is not yet loaded.
Once loaded all is good.